# Where Prestashop 1.5 defined $customerdefaultgroup for use later in product.tpl

Tags: variables, prestashop, var, prestashop-1.5

Where does Prestahop 1.5 defined all vars that I can use alter in product.tpl?

I have an error undefined $customerdefaultgroup if I don't log in as customer, but as soon as I log in, the error will be gone.

Any ideas?

Comment: `customerdefaultgroup` it is not variable that Prestashop use by default, do you have any core changes? It looks like in place where defined `customerdefaultgroup` developer forgot to check if customer logged. Quick way:  just try to find this word in all files, something like `grep -rl 'word-to-search' /dir/with/files` in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Really, you can define lot of vars by using custome module and hook in product.tpl page. So it is hard to answer. By default - Product class. But I have never seen this var, maybe u have installed custom module? Also you could check {debug} in product.tpl but as I remember it gives only all vars not refer to variable module.